# Error while setting role

Tags: php, array, warnings

I already got code which can change role basis on post count.

```
<?php

  add_action( 'save_post', 'update_roles' );
    function update_roles( $post_id ) {

        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return $post_id;

        // Get the author
        $author = wp_get_current_user();

        // Set variables for current user information
        $count = count_user_posts( $author->ID );
        $current_role = (array) get_user_meta( $author->ID, 'wp_capabilities' );

        get_currentuserinfo(); 
        global $user_level;

        // Do the checks to see if they have the roles and if not update them.
        if ( ($user_level != 10) && ( $count > 3 && $count <= 5 ) && ( array_key_exists( 'contributor', $current_role[0] ) ) ) {
            $user_id_role = new WP_User( $author->ID );
            $user_id_role->set_role( 'author' );

        } elseif ( ($user_level != 10) && ( $count > 5 && $count <= 9 ) && ( array_key_exists( 'author', $current_role[0] ) ) ) {

            $user_id_role = new WP_User( $author->ID );
            $user_id_role->set_role( 'editor' );

        } elseif ($user_level != 10){

            $user_id_role = new WP_User( $author->ID );
            $user_id_role->set_role( 'contributor' );

        } return $post_id;

    }

?>
```

Now I have tested on local environent and it was working but now I dont know why it is giving me error as below.

```
Warning: array_key_exists() [function.array-key-exists]: The second argument should be either an array or an object in /home/....../themes/..../inc/functions/user-role.php on line 20

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/....../themes/..../inc/functions/user-role.php) in /home/...../wp-includes/functions.php on line 861
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use just `$current_role` variable instead of `$current_role[0]`, because call `get_user_meta( $author->ID, 'wp_capabilities' );` will return you array with roles as keys.

```
<?php

  add_action( 'save_post', 'update_roles' );
    function update_roles( $post_id ) {

        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return $post_id;

        // Get the author
        $author = wp_get_current_user();

        // Set variables for current user information
        $count = count_user_posts( $author->ID );
        $current_role = (array) get_user_meta( $author->ID, 'wp_capabilities' );

        get_currentuserinfo(); 
        global $user_level;

        // Do the checks to see if they have the roles and if not update them.
        if ( ($user_level != 10) && ( $count > 3 && $count <= 5 ) && ( array_key_exists( 'contributor', $current_role ) ) ) {
            $user_id_role = new WP_User( $author->ID );
            $user_id_role->set_role( 'author' );

        } elseif ( ($user_level != 10) && ( $count > 5 && $count <= 9 ) && ( array_key_exists( 'author', $current_role ) ) ) {

            $user_id_role = new WP_User( $author->ID );
            $user_id_role->set_role( 'editor' );

        } elseif ($user_level != 10){

            $user_id_role = new WP_User( $author->ID );
            $user_id_role->set_role( 'contributor' );

        } return $post_id;

    }

?>
```

Comment: I have tried error gone but now its not changing the role. Is there any other issue?

Comment: @pixelngrain i have updated the code, check it now.

Comment: Thanks let me check.. meanwhile just quick question. Have edited any more things than remove [0]? just for knowledge

Comment: I have checked this code but its not changing the role. i just wonder whats wrong with it. :(